# XSL style sheet for import into Filemaker

Tags: xslt, filemaker

I have been successful importing some elements from a Zotero MODS file into Filemaker using an xsl style sheet. However, some elements seem to be nested within other elements, and I cannot figure out the code.  Here is the part of the .xml file that I want to import:

```
- <relatedItem type="host">
    <genre authority="marcgt">journal</genre> 
  - <part>
    - <detail type="volume">
       <number>3</number> 
      </detail>
```

I want the volume number of the journal to go to a field in Filemaker called "volume". Can anyone help with the code, please?

Here's what I've tried and none of them worked:

```
"mod:part" />
"mod:part/mod:detail[@type='volume']" />
"mod:part/mod:detail[@type='volume']/number" />
"mod:relatedItem[@type='volume']" />
"mod:relatedItem[@type='host']/volume" />
"mod:relatedItem[@type='host']/mod:detail[@type='volume']" />
```

I think I figured it out:

```
"mod:relatedItem[@type='host']/mod:part/mod:detail[@type='volume']" />
```

Now I have another question.  When two elements (like author name) are the same, but only one will import, how do I get both to import?  Here's the example:

```
- <name type="personal">
  <namePart type="family">Cleveland</namePart> 
  <namePart type="given">Jonnie</namePart> 
- <role>
  <roleTerm type="code" authority="marcrelator">aut</roleTerm> 
  </role>
  </name>
- <name type="personal">
  <namePart type="family">Crowe</namePart> 
  <namePart type="given">Margie W</namePart>
```

I've gotten the first author to import using this:

```
         <COL>
          <DATA>
            <xsl:value-of select="mod:name/mod:namePart[@type='family']" />
          </DATA>
        </COL>
        <COL>
          <DATA>
            <xsl:value-of select="mod:name/mod:namePart[@type='given']" />
          </DATA>
        </COL>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you have written so far and exactly which part of it you are stuck on?

Comment: Thank you, Ian.  Here's what I've done so far:

Comment: I don't see any code - use the _edit_ link above to edit the additional information into the question.

Comment: I can't get the whole xslt in this comment box. Thie first example has worked, the second one has not: <COL>
              <DATA>
                <xsl:value-of select="mod:genre[@authority='local']" />
              </DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
              <DATA>
                <xsl:value-of select="mod:relatedItem[@type='host']/part/detail[@type='volume']" />
              </DATA>
            </COL>

Comment: You don't need to put code in comments, just edit the original question.

Comment: You keep trying to edit my answer with comments saying it "didn't work" - instead, please edit _the question_ showing exactly what you've tried, the proper _well-formed_ XML you are using as input, and what output you require.  Without the proper context there's no way we can usefully help as we can't replicate your problem on our own machines - any suggestions will be guesses rather than testable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<COL>
  <DATA>
    <xsl:value-of select="mod:genre[@authority='local']" />
  </DATA>
</COL>
<COL>
  <DATA>
    <xsl:value-of select="mod:relatedItem[@type='host']/part/detail[@type='volume']" />
  </DATA>
</COL>
```

You say the "first one works" which suggests the context here is the `relatedItem` element.  In that case the second `value-of` doesn't need the `relatedItem` bit in the path, but if your original document has a global `xmlns="..."` then it *does* need the namespace prefix on the other steps of the path, try this instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="mod:part/mod:detail[@type='volume']" />
```